# Get all pixels between two pixels

Tags: java, math, graphics, path, lines

Im writing a small painting programm in java, and im stucked on the pen:

Therory: When im dragging the mouse i have to fill the circles between P(draggedX|draggedY) and P2(mouseX|mouseY) with circles. So i have to create a line / a path (?..) and calculate all points that are on it.

What ive tried:

```
double m = 0;
int width = draggedX - mouseX;
int height = draggedY - mouseY;
if(draggedX - mouseX != 0){
    m = (draggedY - mouseY) / (draggedX - mouseX);
}
if(width > 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        double x = mouseX + i;
        double y = mouseY + (m * i);
        g.fillOval((int) x, (int) y, 5, 5);
    }
}
else if(width < 0){
    for(int i = -width; i > 0; i--) {
        double x = mouseX + i;
        double y = mouseY + (m * i);
        g.fillOval((int) x, (int) y, 5, 5);
    }
}
else{
    if(height > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
            g.fillOval(mouseX, (int) i + mouseY, 5, 5);
        }
    }
    else if(height < 0){
        for(int i = -height; i > 0; i--){
            g.fillOval(mouseX, (int) i + mouseY, 5, 5);
        }
    }
}
```

It didnt work correct. sometimes curious lines splashed up and circles werent painted, like this:

[image: paint fail]

Any other ideas, how to solve it? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Java will not generate events for all intermediate points - you can test this by drawing a point at each place where you actually receive an event. If the mouse moves too quickly, you *will* miss points. This happens in all drawing programs.

[Bresenham's line-drawing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) is the traditional way to find integer pixels between two pixels coordinates. But you are programming in Java, and you have something much better: you can trace arbitrary paths, defined through coordinates. Two flavors are available,

The old Graphics version (g is a `Graphics`, possibly from your `paintComponent()` method):

```
// uses current g.setColor(color)
g.drawPolyline(xPoints, yPoints, int nPoints); // xPoints and yPoints are integer arrays
```

And the new Shape-based version (g2d is a `Graphics2D`; your `Graphics` in Swing can be cast to `Graphics2D` without problems):

```
// uses current stroke
g2d.draw(p); // p is a Path2D, build with successive moveTo(point) and lineTo(point)
```

I recommend the second version, since the stroke offers a lot more flexibility (line width, dashes, ...) than just simple colors

Comment: you didnt read my code, i guess.
If i have  2 points from the mouseevent, although i moved 50, i want to draw all circles between this 2. understood now?...

Comment: there's a stroke for that - see examples at http://www.jhlabs.com/java/java2d/strokes/. Also, you can ask Shapes to give you coordinates every X distance units (but Stroke are still the Right Way To Do It (TM).

Answer (score 0):

The division between two integers discards the fractional part: for example 2/3 returns 0. You can use floating point types for computation to keep the fractional parts.

```
double m;
m = (double) (draggedY - mouseY) / (draggedX - mouseX);
```

Comment: good catch, I also am thinking about the event, maybe it doesn't get all the events!

Comment: ooouu thank you that is one of the errors i think ^^
Ill fix it later and tell if it solves the problem! :)
@user2511414: That's the reason, why im drawing all circles between mouseP and dragP ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other answer said, you also need to do your drawing differently if the absolute value of `m` is greater than 1 or not. If it's 1 or less, then you'll want to iterate along the x direction and calculate the y from the slope. Otherwise, you'll need to iterate along the y direction and calculate the m from the (inverse) slope. You have the right idea in the code, but it's not quite implemented correctly. It should be something more like this:

```
if (abs(m) <= 1)
{
    for (int i = startX; i < endX; i++)
    {
        float y = startY + (float)i * m;
        float x = i;
        g.fillOval(x, y, 5, 5);
    }
}
else
{
    for (int i = startY; i < endY; i++)
    {
        float x = startX + (float)i / m;
        float y = i;
        g.fillOval(x, y, 5, 5);
    }
}
```